# Quickbooks PHP API Authentication issue

Tags: php, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I'm using QuickBooks REST API v3.0. When I am trying to get customer details with it then it gives authentication error as below.

> The Status code: 401
>
> The Helper message: Invalid auth/bad request (got
> a 401, expected HTTP/1.1 20X or a redirect)
>
> The Response message:
> message=ApplicationAuthenticationFailed; errorCode=003200;
> statusCode=401
>
> SignatureBaseString:
> POST&https%3A%2F%2Fsandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com%2Fv3%2Fcompany%2FCOMPANY%2Fquery&minorversion%3D9%26oauth_consumer_key%3DCONSUMER_KEY%26oauth_nonce%3DrssGZq%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1501562920%26oauth_token%3DAUTH_TOKEN%26oauth_version%3D1.0

I'm using new access token so there is not issue with it.
So What is the issue? Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.